# Continuity in the weak operator topology implies continuity in the strong op. top.?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. I would like to show:

A $\phi : \mathcal{B(H)}\to\mathbb{C}$ linear functional is continous in the strong operator-topology iff is continous in the weak operator-topology.

The SOT $\Rightarrow$ WOT implication is clear, but the reverse is not.

Comment: The question now makes sense, but now you have it the wrong way around. The trivial direction is "WOT$\implies$ SOT"

Comment: $\phi$ is WOT-continous iff for every WOT-convergent sequence $A_n\to A\in B(H)$ we have $\phi(A_n)\to\phi(A)$.

If you replace "WOT" with "SOT" in that statement, you make the assumption stronger, so the statement becomes weaker.

Comment: Yes, I had realised and deleted my comment.

Comment: no problem :) it really is quite confusing

Comment: You're right again, but somehow, I figured out the more difficult direction. =D Maybe I'm a bit tired, sorry. =)
So thanks, you answered my question.

Comment: Also, since WOT and SOT are not metrizisable, it is not enough to check simply that the implication holds on the level of sequential continuity.

Comment: just replace "sequence" with "net". Also: I would be interested in the "SOT$\implies$ WOT" proof, as that is the non-trivial one.

Comment: For the proof of the other direction, I use a lemma, that is: If $\mathcal{V}$ is a topological vectorspace. and $\phi\neq 0$ linear functional, then the followings are equivalent:
(1) $\phi$ is continous,
(2) $Ker \phi$ is closed,
(3) $Ker \phi$ is not dense,
(4) there exists an open set $W$ such that $0\in W$, and $\phi\vert_W$ is bounded.

After the proof of the lemma, its quite easy to show the other implication:

$\phi$ is SOT continous $\Rightarrow$ $Ker\phi$ SOT closed $\Rightarrow$ $Ker\phi$ WOT closed $\Rightarrow$ $\phi$ WOT continous.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ is WOT-continous iff for every WOT-convergent net $A_n\to A\in\mathcal{B(H)}$ we have $\phi(A_n)\to\phi(A)$. If you replace "WOT" with "SOT" in that statement, you make the assumption stronger, so the statement becomes weaker.

Comment: just replace "sequence" with "net", and it works.

Comment: right, sometimes I wonder whether I think at all

Comment: @s.harp well, I wasn't thinking too much either. I though "hey, $\mathbb{C}$ is metric, so sequences are enough"... which is not true.